# I'm unable to include using.SignalR.Hubs on my ASP.NET MVC 4 application.. VS 2012 prompts 'SignalR' could not be found. How to resolve this issue?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012, signalr

I'm unable to include using.`SignalR`.Hubs in my `ASP.NET MVC 4` application..

VS 2012 prompts `'SignalR' could not be found`. How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the appropriate SignalR packages?

You should use NuGet to get them installed correctly.

It looks as though, at a minimum you'll need: Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR

See here:
https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Getting-Started

Answer (score 0):

If you installed it using: `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR -Pre` you should do `using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.Hubs;`.

Only if you installed it using `Install-Package SignalR` then it is `using SignalR.Hubs;`.

The first one is supported by microsoft and forked from the open source version.